# How to make favicon.ico Small and Cacheable?

Tags: caching, favicon

I have a favicon.ico in my asp.net web application. It is small but how to make it cacheable? Any suggestion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

favicons are already cached by client browsers. That's often an issue when you modify the icon you need to clear your browser cache for changes to take effect.

Answer (score 1):

try out to shrink it , favicon.cc provide a good simple free way [link] http://www.favicon.cc/ download the .ico , maybe you can have a test on getmetriks.com it provide a nice tool for cookies and cacheable favicon. visit [link]http://gtmetrix.com/make-favicon-small-and-cacheable.html

Answer (score 0):

check your server logs. favicon is often the most common download. If it is, there should be a section in the manual dealing with cache and proxy control. Details depend on the server.